# 'Ambiguity' of dual vectors $\{dx^i\}$ in cotangent space in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, distance

The metric tensor is defined as:

$$g = g_{ij}dx^i \otimes dx^j,$$

where I used the summation convention. We often omit the tensor product sign $\otimes$ and just write this as:

$$g = g_{ij}dx^idx^j.$$

My question is about the line element which is also written as:

$$ds^2 = g_{ij}dx^i dx^j.$$

I will describe what I already know about the metric tensor and line element below.

Suppose we have a Riemannian manifold $M$, then we can define at every point $p\in M$ a metric. This give raise to the metric tensor field (so for every point $p$ we get a tensor:), so $g_p: T_p M\times T_p M\rightarrow \mathcal{R}$, where $\mathcal{R}$ are the real numbers. The coordinates $\{x^i\}$ are then local coordinates at $p$. From this notion we can define the length of a path $\gamma : [a,b]\rightarrow M $ with the property that $\gamma(t)\in M$ for $t\in[a,b]$. We can define the length of this path as:

$$L_\gamma = \int^b_a\sqrt{\pm g_{ij}\frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{dx^j}{dt}}dt = \int^b_a\sqrt{\pm g_{ij}dx^idx^j}=\int^b_ads.$$

Where the $\pm$ ensures that we get a real solution.

From this we see that the line element can be defined as:

$$ds^2 = g_{ij}dx^idx^j.$$

The problem that I have with this, is that $L_\gamma \in \mathcal{R}$ is a *real number*. It now seems that we did not use the idea that $dx^i$ is a dual vector in the cotangent space defined at every point $p \in M$, but that we now regard those differentials as infinitesemal displacements (since only then they add up to a length).

I am not sure what happens here, I also read other posts but they seem to skip the point that the dual vectors $dx^i$ get an ambiguous meaning. For example if we consider the arc length in Cartesian coordinates and we let $M=\mathcal{R}^2$, then we get the following expression for the length of some curve:

$$L = \int^b_a \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2},$$

but how is this elementary notion of calculus consistent with the idea that $dx^i$ is a dual vector (so that $dx^2$ would actually be a *tensor* of rank (0,2))? Now it seems that everyone just assumes that the square root of the metric tensor is well-defined and that this evaluates to a scalar. Could somebody elaborate a bit more on this idea? The idea what a length and the metric tensor and so on is, is quite clear for me.

Comment: @mavzolej please do not link to illegal copies of copyrighted materials.

Comment: @KyleKanos: We have no way of knowing what the copyright laws are where mavzolej lives. A more reasonable expectation might be that mavzolej note in the comment that the link is to a pirated copy of the book. The textbook market is so economically exploitative that I often make a point of mentioning to my students that Library Genesis exists.

Comment: @BenCrowell my understanding is that it doesn't matter where mavzolej lives, only that the servers on which we are all accessing are based in the US & so such copyright infringement laws in the US should be applied. I believe there are plenty of Mother Meta posts about it, if you're interested in learning about the position of SE on such thievery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a curve $\gamma:I\to M$, one can pull back the (positive definite) metric tensor $${\bf g}~=~ g_{ij}\mathrm{d}x^i \odot \mathrm{d}x^i~\in~ \Gamma\left( {\rm Sym}^2(T^{\ast}M)\right)\tag{A}$$ to 
$$\omega\odot\omega~:=~\gamma^{\ast}{\bf g}~\in~ \Gamma\left( {\rm Sym}^2(T^{\ast}I)\right),\tag{B}$$
where the 1-form $\omega$ is locally exact $$\omega~=~\mathrm{d}s\tag{C}$$ because of [Poincare lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) $\mathrm{d}\omega=0$. Now to get a function on both sides of eq. (B) insert a vector field $X\in  \Gamma(TI)$ twice on both sides of eq. (B). This will essentially reproduce what physicists mean by the formula
$$ ds^2 ~=~g_{ij}dx^idx^j. \tag{D} $$

Comment: How do you insert a vector field in $\Gamma(TI)$ into the right hand side of (B)?

Answer (score 5):

The mismatch with the notations
$$g= g_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j$$ and 
 $$ds^2 = g_{ij}dx^idx^j$$ is due to the fact that, in this  second formula the $dx^k$s correspond to "small" components of **contravariant vectors** $\delta X$ (the $dx^k$s are *real numbers* here) instead of elements of the dual basis (the $dx^i$ are covariant *vectors* in the rigorous view). Replacing in the second formula $dx^k$ with a less ambiguous notation $\delta x^k$,
$$\delta X = \delta x^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$$
Therefore we have the identity connecting the two notions
$$ g_{ij} \delta x^i \delta x^j = g(\delta X, \delta X) = \delta s^2\:.$$
 This interpretation is also in agreement with the integral defining the length of a curve provided we write $\dot{\gamma} dt = \delta x^i  \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, so that the formula for computing the length of a curve becomes
$$L_\gamma = \int_a^b \sqrt{|g(\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma})|} dt = \int \sqrt{|g_{ij}\delta x^i\delta x^j|}\:.$$
The point is that the objects $\delta x^k$ do not exist as "infinitesimal numbers" (unless taking advantage of the nonstandard analysis) while the objects $dx^i$ do exist as vectors in a suitable vector space and this notation is therefore more rigorous from the mathematical viewpoint.

Why do the two ideas work in agreement? The reason is that **infinitesimal** is replaced, in the modern view, with **linear approximation** (first order Taylor expansion neglecting infinitesimals of higer order) and vectors are linear structures embodying the information of these linear approximations.