# General Relativity - Short hand intuition vs Formal description

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

I would like to understand a bit better some concepts in GR. Let's start with the metric. So usually we introduce

$$ds^2= g_{\mu \nu} dx^{\mu} dx^{\nu}$$
saying something like: $ds^2$ is the line element so the infinitesimal interval for infinitesimal coordinates displacement $dx^{\mu}$. So in this view, it is natural to define the action of a free particle
$$
S=-m\int ds \tag{1} 
$$
or the proper time like

$$-d\tau^2= ds^2$$
using $\tau$ to parametrize the world-line. But now if we want to be more precise $ds^2$ is a $(0,2)$ tensor so an object that gets 2 vectors as arguments and gives me a number. So we write:

$$ds^2= g_{\mu \nu} dx^{\mu} \otimes dx^{\nu}\tag{2}$$
where $dx^{\mu}$ now is the dual vector of the basis. So here come the questions. How can we connect this view with the intuitive idea of $ds^2$ as the line element? How can we interpret now the proper time being it a tensor as well? And what is the meaning of the integral in $(1)$?

Moreover when we consider now a particular trajectory for a particle, saying it moves keeping $x$ and $y$ constant, how come we can just write

$$ ds^2=-dt^2+dz^2$$
What is the meaning of saying $dx=dy=0$?

Comment: Why do you think $ds^2$ is a (0,2) tensor?

Comment: The metric is a (0,2) tensor.  I think you're confounding the metric with the infinitesimal line element $ds$?

Comment: There seems to be some variation in what exactly people define as "the spacetime interval". In some cases $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$, in which case this object is certainly a rank-2 tensor (with $\otimes$ suppressed). Other times people write $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}\Delta x^\mu \Delta x^\nu$ in which case this is a Lorentz scalar. I asked this question about a year ago [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/517993/is-the-spacetime-interval-a-tensor). I'm not commenting on which is correct (or more common), simply that this is what I have seen.

Comment: You're asking too many questions for one post. Some of your statements are wrong, you're confusing scalars with tensors. Your last sentence states that there is no displacement in the x and y axes. I cannot write right now an answer to answer all questions, I will do so first chance if no one answer your questions.

Comment: @ApolloRa I think the question are all related to the same issue. Is $d^2s$ a (0,2) tensor? If so, how can we use the interpretation and do all the things that we did when considering it just as a Lorentz scalar.

Comment: @Brick the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ are the component of the metric tensor. In fact, they change when changing the coordinates; $g_{\mu \nu}$ is not a geometrical object. I think it is clear from $(2)$ that $ds^2$ is a tensor.

Comment: @Charlie I think it is always a rank-2 tensor, I should have written more explicitly: $ds^2=-dt \otimes dt + dz \otimes dz$

Comment: I actually found another interesting answer besides @Charlie 's, here's the link https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/431714/ambiguity-of-dual-vectors-dxi-in-cotangent-space-in-general-relativity

Comment: The confusion stems from ambiguous notation that is common in physics, in that we often call $dx$ an "infinitesimal change in $x$", instead of a 1-form which is what a mathematician would call it. Thus $g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ in physics means "feed the metric tensor two infinitesimal vectors to obtain a scalar", even though formally that notation is reserved for defining the metric itself as a rank-2 tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I addressed [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3740078/568204) a while back; long story short, $g$ is the metric tensor field (a $(0,2)$ tensor field on the manifold $M$), and the line element $ds^2$ should be interpreted as the associated quadratic function (though sometimes people do use $ds^2$ to mean the actual metric tensor field $g$ itself, though I don't like this).

The meaning of the integral is as follows: we fix a smooth manifold $M$ and $g$ a non-degenerate symmetric $(0,2)$ tensor field on $M$ (this takes into account the Riemannian and Lorentzian case in any dimension), and suppose $\gamma:[a,b]\to M$ is a smooth curve ($C^1$ or even piece-wise $C^1$ would work), and we suppose in addition that for each $t\in [a,b]$, we have $ds^2_{\gamma(t)}[\gamma'(t)]:= g_{\gamma(t)}[\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t)]\geq 0$ (here I use $\gamma'(t)$ to denote the velocity vector, which is an element of the tangent space $T_{\gamma(t)}M$). We now consider the speed of $\gamma$, which is a function $\sigma:[a,b]\to \Bbb{R}$ defined as
\begin{align}
\sigma(t):= \sqrt{ds^2_{\gamma(t)}[\gamma'(t)]} := \sqrt{g_{\gamma(t)}[\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t)]}
\end{align}
This function is well-defined because the thing under the square root is $\geq 0$ by assumption. Also this is the square root of a continuous function of $t$, hence it is continuous, hence Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$. So, now the meaning of the integral is
\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma}ds:= \int_a^b \sigma(t)\, dt := \int_a^b\sqrt{g_{\gamma(t)}[\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t)]}\, dt.
\end{align}
(i.e if you integrate the speed of the curve, you get its length).
If we further assume we have a coordinate chart $(U,x)$ such that the image of $\gamma$ lies entirely in $U$, then we can write this as
\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma}ds&=\int_a^b\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}(\gamma(t))(x^{\mu}\circ \gamma)'(t)
(x^{\mu}\circ \gamma)'(t)}\, dt
\end{align}
or more concisely, $\int_{\gamma}ds= \int_a^b\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{dt}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{dt}}\, dt$, which is of course an abuse of notation since $x^{\mu}$ is being used twice with different meanings (the point is that the coordinate functions $x^{\mu}$ become functions along the curve simply by composition $x^{\mu}\circ \gamma$)... but anyway many books often write this only so its a good idea to get used to this.

For your final question, if $(U,x)$ is a coordinate chart on the manifold $M$, then saying something like $dx^{\mu}=0$ is technically an incorrect statement, since $dx^{\mu}$ is NOT the zero differential form. What is meant is that if you have a curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to M$, then the pullback form
\begin{align}
\gamma^*(dx^{\mu})= d(\gamma^*x^{\mu})= d(x^{\mu}\circ \gamma) = (x^{\mu}\circ \gamma)'\, dt
\end{align}
is the zero differential form on $[a,b]$ (and $t$ denotes the usual coordinate function on this interval).

For example, suppose the manifold is $M= \Bbb{R}^4$, and $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$ are the "cartesian coordinates". Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to M=\Bbb{R}^4$ be the curve $\gamma(t)= (\cos t e^{-t^2\int_0^t\arctan(e^{-\lambda})\,d\lambda}, 89, t^7, e^{t\ln(2+ \sin t)})$. Then, you see the $x^1$ component of $\gamma$ is constant; i.e $\gamma^1(t):= (x^1\circ \gamma)(t) = 89$ for all $t\in [0,1]$, then we often write $dx^1=0$, when we really mean $d(x^1\circ \gamma)=0$ (because $(x^1\circ\gamma)'(t)=0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$). Often times, we don't bother introducing a new letter $\gamma$ for a curve... this is just something to get used to.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the world line as a 1D submanifold embedded in 4D space-time. The metric $ds^2$ can then be pulled back through the inclusion map to this 1D curve. The 1D volume is then $ds$, which is formally $\sqrt{\det (ds^2)}$. For the world line using the OP's notation, it would be $\sqrt{-\det(ds^2)}$, a pseudo-1-form measuring proper time.

Answer (score 0):

The discussion under the question about the notation is, I'm starting to think, the seed of an answer to the "intuition" part of this question at least.  I'm going to pull at that part of it to see if that either answers the question or gives enough of a partial answer that someone else can add something complementary.

This is how I think about it - so if you find this not formally correct, we'll call it my intuition:

1. The metric is $g_{ab}$, which is a (0,2) tensor.  There's some abuse of notation here in that I use the same symbol $g_{ab}$ for the whole tensor and for its components, and I might have to separate those cases out by context.  For sure, as noted in the comments to the question, an individual component of this tensor changes with a change in coordinates, but the set of them change in just the right way for this to be a tensor.
2. For two points on the manifold separated by finite (coordinate) displacement $\Delta x^a$ (a vector - again abusing notation so that the same symbol might mean the whole vector or a single component of it, depending on context), the interval between them is *approximately* $\Delta s = \left(g_{ab} \Delta x^a \Delta x^b\right)^{1/2}$, which is a scalar. Specifically it is a scalar formed from the contraction of a (0,2) tensor with two (1,0) tensors.
3. The spacetime interval $ds$ is the limit of this expression as $\Delta x^a \rightarrow 0$.  I still treat that like a scalar because the finite $\Delta s$ was a scalar.
4. Not sure what it means to you, but $ds^2$ to me, intuitively is $(ds)^2$, meaning it is the square of an infinitesimal distance.

There are a lot of conventions about how to deal with the ambiguity in the notation.  Some people adopt completely different notation for the tensor as a whole vs. the components, some use Latin vs. Greek indices to denote the difference, etc.  My personal, intuitive sense is that this really makes no difference in practice most of the time, at least for the problems that I've personally worked.  So long as one is working with combinations of tensors that are themselves tensors or scalars (e.g. $g_{ab} \Delta x^a$ summed / contracted on $a$ is ok, but $g_{ab} \Delta x^0$ is now a coordinate expression that could cause concern or require more care).  Also, to the extent that much of the work that I've personally seen is numerical and therefore finite, one always has a finite $\Delta s$ and the infinitesimal $ds$ is an abstraction that is never reached.  Once in a while the intuition might break down or you just confuse yourself and need to back up and be more careful.

Whether or not it passes muster with you for formality, we now have some intuitive answers to your specific questions:

1. How do we connect your formal sense of "$ds^2$ to a line element?  It is the limit of taking smaller and smaller segments of a path between two spacetime points, which connects to your third question below.
2. How can we interpret the proper time as tensor?  Well, I don't ever do that.  Proper time is a scalar related to the scalar notion of $ds$ above.
3. What is the meaning of the integral in Eq. (1) of the question?  The integral is the limit of summing those finite estimates to $\Delta x^a$ as the segments get shorter and shorter.  Physically this is related to the energy of the particle.
4. What is the meaning of $dx = dy = 0$?  It means that we've got a constraint on the dynamics that the particle never moves in the coordinate $x$ or coordinate $y$ direction, as those coordinates are defined at the location of the particle.  Of course if you change the coordinates, you will still have some constraint, but it will not be amenable to such a concise description.

Now it is clear that some of these intuitive notions are not fully rigorous.  But I don't see that as any different than treating a Dirac delta function as if it's a real function most of the time.  That's not formally correct either, and sometimes you can get to a case where the difference really matters and you need to step back and be careful. (Or run to your nearest true mathematician.)  But most of the time the meaning is clear enough and the mechanics of dealing with it are well enough established that the difference doesn't change the answer to the problem that you're actually trying to solve.